# Saving an integer onClick so it can be called back later on in the android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors, onclick

My probablem is I have all the code and there is no errors on it (accrording to eclipse) but when I try to open up "page1" on my app it freezes then crashes, if I get ride of all of the addPoints information the page runs fine, can you help me find out what is causing the crash? Thanks!
heres my code

```
package com.canadais.civics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class page1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

    TextView Q1A1;
    TextView Q1A2;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    public int testScore = (settings.getInt("YourScore", 0));
    Intent page2 = new Intent (this, Page2.class);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        Q1A1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1A1);
        Q1A2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Q1A2);
        Q1A1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Q1A2.setOnClickListener(this);
        //test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);






        //test.setText(settings.getInt("YourScore", 0));


    }
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.Q1A1:
            addPoints(10);
            //Intent page2 = new Intent (this, Page2.class);
            startActivity(page2);
            break;
        case R.id.Q1A2:
            addPoints(5);
            //Intent page22 = new Intent (this, Page2.class);
            startActivity(page2);
            break;
        }   
    }



    public void addPoints(int points) 
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("YourScore", (testScore + points));
        editor.commit();       
    }

}
```

Comment: Post crash message. logcat error messages.

Comment: When I run the app on my tablet and click on the button that is supposed to open the page that I have show the code for you it says "The application Canada Is (process com.canadais.civics) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Comment: You should show your logcat to find out error

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons if you encounter problems after executing *startActivity()*. I can think of two right now:

1. Missing Activity declaration in *AndroidManifest.xml*;
2. Incorrect codes in the Activity(*Page2.java* in your case) to be started.

To ensure which error you have encountered, I suggest you should learn to post error message appeared in the LogCat which is bundled in Android SDK but not the one pop-up on the phone screen, otherwise, no one could accurately figure out the problem(s).

Comment: The thing is if I put "//" infront of all the "addPoints" information the app runs fine, also I have no errors on the screen.

Comment: I believe most of us here are expecting the error message showing in LogCat, but not "The application Canada Is (process com.canadais.civics) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."(in which I refer this as the error pop-up on screen). Back to the topic, it seems that the error scope is within **addPoints()** method according to your description, but still we need more information of error message to figure out your problem faster.